# Google Geocoding doesn't return a good result

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I don't understand how Geocoding request should be formulated to always return an expected result.

I try to know all cities of Apremont in France for example.
So I send the request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Apremont,fr
```

But it only returns an apremont in Vendée, 85.

Now, if I send the following request,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Apremont,fr,26

it effectively find all Apremont in France (26, 73, 85, etc...), and more but here is not the subject.

So, how to format the request to ask geocoding to returns all cities of Apremont?

Regards,

Comment: I have found some new ways to achieve it. is your problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find out latitude and longitude  of particular adress

```
@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true"
```

Send that latitude and longitude to

`@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&amp;sensor=false"`

and you will be able to get multiple location near by that particular latitude and longitude

Comment: Send that latitude and longitude to @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&amp;sensor=false" and you will be able to get multiple location near by tthat particular latitude and longitude . Hope that you have found the solutions

Comment: thanks but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd want all cities matching the given name in the given country.

Comment: I faced same problem and did so . and gives the solutions

Comment: Ok, I'm going to test it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you find the solutions

Comment: Ok, it's a workaround but needs 2 geocoding requests which can be a quotas problem and after the answer analysis is a quite big job. I still looking for a 'correct' answer from Google geocoding

Comment: Yes we need two requests .. If it works then   i am waiting for your response by up-vote. If you find correct answer please post it. I will also try to implement that